# Warning for variable Multiple Definition

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

I was expecting error message (or atleast the warning) for multiple definition of variable var1 below. That means is this not a multiple definition? Is the scope of the variable inside the main is different from its scope outside the main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int var1;
int main (void)
{
    int var1;
    var1=12;
    printf("%d",var1);
}
```

Comment: Add `-Wshadow` to your compiler flags to receive a warning. See [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the scope of the variable inside the main is different from its scope outside the main.

Yes. They are two different variables. Hence, there is no multiple variable definition error.

Verify it using the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var1;
void foo();

int main (void)
{
    int var1;
    var1=12;
    printf("%d\n",var1);
    foo();
}

void foo()
{
    var1=20;
    printf("%d\n",var1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not multiple definitions, because they *are* in different scopes. In the scope of `main()`, you have a different variable. Normally, variables from outer scopes are alive in inner scopes, too, but having a variable of the same name *shadows* the variable of the outer scope.

That said, it's often just *bad practice*, as it can easily lead to bugs having multiple variables of the same name. A compiler *could* try to detect this and warn about it, but that would probably lead to many false positives as it's legal after all and sometimes there are good uses.

Edit: as cremno points out in a comment, GCC (and thus mingw) is able to show such warnings with the flag `-Wshadow`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, those are different variables as far as the compiler is concerned. the int var1 that is declared outside of your main function lives in the global scope which is accessible to ALL functions in your program (that are declared in the same file or other files compiledand linked together using extern).

the variable int var1 that you declared in your Main function lives in the stack frame inside which your Main function is running. Although legal, what you are doing is generally not considered good practice and you should avoid it unless you have a very good reason otherwise